# Sumproduct in different workbook and mulriple sheet

Tags: excel, excel-formula, sum

Hi i wanna ask about excel program.
First I have 2 workbooks, "stock" and "160601".

In workbook "160601" :

Sheet 1 :
XYZ 1

Sheet 2 :
XYZ 4

In workbook "stock" :

I want
XYZ 5

Can i use sumproduct formula ?

Thank you

Comment: Yes, you should be able to but there is not enough information in your question to answer it an more succinctly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming your worksheets are as follows:

Workbook: **`160601`** Sheet: **`Sheet1`**

[image]

Workbook: **`160601`** Sheet: **`Sheet2`**

[image]

You'll need to have names of all the sheets of `160601` workbook in `sheet1` of `stock` workbook. Below I've used Cell E4 and E5 to write names of the sheet of `160601` workbook.
Then write the following formula in `Sheet1` of `stock` workbook:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(SUMIF(INDIRECT("'[16061.xlsx]"&$E$4:$E$5&"'!A1:A2"),A1,INDIRECT("'[16061.xlsx]"&$E$4:$E$5&"'!B1:B2")))
```

Workbook: **`stock`** Sheet: **`Sheet1`**

[image]

**EDIT# 1**
**______________________________________________________________________________**

When workbook is closed `INDIRECT` and `SUMIF` will not work.
Alternatively, you can use following formula (looks little ugly):

```
=SUM(SUMPRODUCT(--('C:\test_folder\test\[16061.xlsx]Sheet1'!A1:A2=A1),'C:\test_folder\test\[16061.xlsx]Sheet1'!B1:B2),SUMPRODUCT(--('C:\test_folder\test\[16061.xlsx]Sheet2'!A1:A2=A1),'C:\test_folder\test\[16061.xlsx]Sheet2'!B1:B2))
```

Comment: I want ask if the workbook 16061 closed. there is error in workbook stock. can I get the value even the workbook is close ?

Comment: @user3551629 - See my Edit# 1.

Comment: You're right. if in 16061 I want make more than 5 sheet. so I just add sumproduct again in formula that u edited ?

Comment: @user3551629 - As per my formula, you'll have to add `SUMPRODUCT` for each sheet.